# How to have parent record data available when a child one is deleted through cascade

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Consider the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE public.parent
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('parent_id_seq'::regclass),
  CONSTRAINT pk_parent PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE public.child
(
  child_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('child_child_id_seq'::regclass),
  parent_id bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_child PRIMARY KEY (child_id),
  CONSTRAINT inx_parent FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
      REFERENCES public.parent (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE INDEX fki_child
  ON public.child
  USING btree
  (parent_id);

CREATE TRIGGER child_trg
  BEFORE DELETE
  ON public.child
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.trg();
```

And the `trg` is defined as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.trg()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$BEGIN
    INSERT INTO temp
    SELECT p.id
    FROM parent p
    WHERE
        p.id = OLD.parent_id;
    return OLD;
END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

To sum up what is happening, there're two tables with a simple parent-child relationship and a cascade on it. There's also a trigger defined on child listening to deletion. I need to access parent's data, in the trigger, when the child's records are deleted due to cascade on parent-child relation. But I can not since they are already deleted! Does anyone have any idea how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to create a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger on `parent` ***instead***, which can see *all* data.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.trg_parent()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO some_tbl (id)  -- use target list !!
   VALUES (OLD.parent_id);

   RETURN OLD;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER parent_trg
BEFORE DELETE ON public.parent
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.trg_parent();
```

Comment: Almost right, you need to write two triggers, one for the parent and one for the child, in case the child is being deleted directly. Thanks.

Comment: @Mehran: You stated `child's records are deleted due to cascade on parent-child relation`. The additional trigger you mention doesn't seem to be within the scope of this question.

Comment: You are right, but that was because in my original question such a problem didn't exist, it is introduced once you move the trigger to the parent table. I'm not saying that you're answer is wrong, it's just that in my case I had to write two of them to compensate for the direct deletion. Thanks anyway.